# G-Sync Not Working

Tags: nvidia

I uninstalled Ubuntu in rage this week. But I want to try and re
 install it this weekend and try to figure out my problem.

Basically my only problem with Ubuntu is that my G-Sync doesn't   activate when I run a game.

I had 14.04 installed alongside the newest Nvidia driver for my GTX   780ti graphics card. I clicked to enable G-sync in the nvidia software. But every time I loaded a game from my steam library, it never activated G-Sync.

I would love to ditch Windows for good, but I'm not letting my $600 monitor go to waste. If someone could give me an answer to why it never activated that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Al right, I solved my problem. If you are using dual monitors, you have to disable the non g-sync monitor in order for this to work.